# Installation PROBLEM : unity Ubuntu-Desktop

Tags: unity, software-installation, desktop-environments

Currently I am using Gnome-Shell but now I want to use unity Desktop.
I tried to install ubuntu-desktop by following command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Its showing following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to download and install these packages externally and then use the command sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @Raphael 14.04,nope

Comment: I think downloading those packages externally might help.

Comment: Do you want me to write an answer with the how to?

Comment: @Raphael yes please

Comment: But first would please try to individually install the packages like: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session; sudo apt-get install unity-control-center; sudo apt-get install unity-settings-daemon. Please comment if you find any error then.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (< 3.10) but 3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Download "Synaptics Package Manager" and delete all the broken packages from under the "Custom Filters" Tab.

Comment: try this just type `sudo apt-get install -f' and post the output in comments or upload it to paste bin or take a screenshot of it

Comment: @romaan 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.

Comment: now its showing

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Raphael Synaptic manager is showing o broken packages.

Comment: i think you should follow this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages

Comment: Okay guys, this isn't a dupe of that, but it isn't possible. There is a message on the gnome 3 website talking about how you can't use unity with it.